# AlertDialog: Can't keep dialog when the condition fails

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have an AlertDialog with a view as shown below.

```
userEmail = new EditText(mActivity);
userEmail.setSingleLine(true);

userEmail.setHint("Email address");
userEmail.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
userEmail.addTextChangedListener(this);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.text_dialog_email));
builder.setView(userEmail);
```

I have added a POSITIVE button to it with an event listener.

```
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          if(userEmail.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                userEmail.setError("Email address can't be empty");
          } else {
                  //some logic

                 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userEmail.getWindowToken(), 0);

                 dialog.dismiss(); 
           }

} });

builder.create();
builder.show();
```

There is an email validation when user hits ok button. I was expecting the dialog to stay if the Edittext is empty. However, in real, dialog disappears even if the EditText is empty.

Is there anything I am lacking?

**EDIT**

The whole code is inside a method, openEmailDialog(). It is invoked on a buttonclick.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   openEmailDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `onClickListener` via the builder, the dialog will automatically close.

You can prevent this, by manually adding the `View.OnClickListener` to the `Button` view of the dialog. You can receive the `Button` `View` from the dialog, after it has been shown.

You should try this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);//init button
final AlertDialog d = builder.create();//store reference to the dialog
//the click listener for your button
final View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
         if(userEmail.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
            userEmail.setError("Email address can't be empty");
      } else {
              //some logic

             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userEmail.getWindowToken(), 0);

             d.dismiss(); 
       }
    }
});

d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog){
        //here get the Button and set onclicklistener
        Button b = d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        b.setOnClickListener(myListener);//your validation in your onclicklistener.
        //do not forget to dismiss the dialon in your View.OnClickListener
    } 

});
d.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this problem by using Java Reflection.

```
 private void canCloseDialog(DialogInterface dialogInterface, boolean close) {  
     try {  
         Field field = dialogInterface.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mShowing");

         field.setAccessible(true);  
         field.set(dialogInterface, close);  
     } catch (Exception e) {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
     }  
 }
```

Call this method at the onClick callback

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  
         .setTitle(R.string.abc)  
         .setView(passwdEditText)  
         .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
             @Override  
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {  
                 canCloseDialog(dialogInterface, false);//will NOT close the Dialog
             }  
         })  
         .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
             @Override  
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {  

                 canCloseDialog(dialogInterface, true);//will close the Dialog
             }  
         })  
         .show();
```